# Mysql looping through temporary table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set a query result to a variable and then use that result in another query.

So right now I have several type of Whiskeys in my ingredients table and I can find all of them and with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (Ingredient_Id int); 
Insert into TempTable Select Ingredient_Id from ingredients where INSTR(Ingredient_Name,'Whiskey')>0;
```

Which gives me all my id's that I need. Then I am trying to get the relevant data with:

```
select drink_names.*,ingredients.*, drink_recipes.*
from drink_recipes
Left JOIN drink_names ON drink_recipes.Drink_Id = drink_names.Drink_Id
Left JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.Ingredient_Id = drink_recipes.Ingredient_Id
where drink_recipes.Ingredient_Id in TempTable #This is the problem
Order By Drink_Name
```

I am at a loss of how to run this query with each id in the `TempTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select drink_names.*,ingredients.*, drink_recipes.*
from drink_recipes
Left JOIN drink_names ON drink_recipes.Drink_Id = drink_names.Drink_Id
Left JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.Ingredient_Id = drink_recipes.Ingredient_Id
where drink_recipes.Ingredient_Id in 
(
  Select Ingredient_Id 
  from ingredients 
  where INSTR(Ingredient_Name,'Whiskey')>0
)
Order By Drink_Name
```

or you can also try

```
select drink_names.*,ingredients.*, drink_recipes.*
from drink_recipes
Left JOIN drink_names ON drink_recipes.Drink_Id = drink_names.Drink_Id
Left JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.Ingredient_Id = drink_recipes.Ingredient_Id
                      AND INSTR(ingredients.Ingredient_Name,'Whiskey') > 0
Order By Drink_Name
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Don't even need the temp table.